# AI bias in the sentiment analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

Using sentiment analysis API and want to know how the AI bias that gets in through the training set of data and other biases quantified. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the use case that you are trying.

Comment: Behavioral testing of NLP models with the checklist, Please follow the below checklist. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.04118.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools developed to deal with it:
Fair Learn https://fairlearn.github.io/
Interpretability Toolkit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-machine-learning-interpretability

In Fair Learn you can see how biased a ML model is after it has been trained with the data set and choose a maybe less accurate model which performs better with biases. The explainable ML models provide different correlation of inputs with outputs and combined with Fair Learn can give an idea of the health of the ML model.